# What is the origin of the Russians' endonym?

Tags: etymology

Just to recap. In Old Nordic something along the lines of "Rods" meant "rowers", "men who row" → then it gave name to one Swedish coastal region, "Roslagen" → then the whole of Sweden, "Ruodsi" of some sort (all were endonyms, as far as I understand) → then the Varangians came along, they called themselves "Rus" or whatever → then Oleg conquered Kiev and named the whole region "Kievan Rus" (as opposed to the "original" Rus that was Sweden) → then the locals kind of accepted that rule and started to call themselves "Rus" too (but they had called themselves something before the Scandinavians invaded, didn't they; what that was I wonder). Is it correct? Please rectify my account if necessary

Comment: The term "Kievan Rus" (_Киевская Русь_)  wasn't used in the Middle Ages, it was coined in the 19th century in Russian historiography to refer to the period when the center was in Kyiv. What you wrote is just one hypothesis, there are [other various etymologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Rus%27,_Russia_and_Ruthenia) of the word _Rus’_.